# How do i make it so that if you press a button and then a different button you will get something written on your screen?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Okey, so it may sound confusing, but this is what i want to do:

You have 4 buttons. Button A, button B, button C, and button D. If you press button B and button C it will say for example "hi". Then if you press B and A it will say "Hello". So different button combinations will give you different "results" i guess.

Anyone have an idea on how i could do this? I do not have much experience with java script so it would be higly appreciated if someone would help me. :-)

Answer (score 0):

So you have about 16 different cases of what your Result might be.

I would recommend you a swtich case statement for the 16 results.

You could set a var for the click events to define the cases.

```
switch(expression) {
case x:
    // code block
return "hi"
    break;
  case y:
    // code block
return "Hello"
    break;
  default:
    // code block
}
```

each button combination will give you a another state
see also [W3Schools JS switch case](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Normally, we're not supposed to write your code and develop your solution for you (it's not Stackoverflow's point), but in this case it's just a fun little exercise, so here goes :

```js
const combinations = {
  aa: "You clicked A then A",
  ab: "Hello AB",
  ac: "Hi!",
  // ...
  cb: "You clicked C then B"
  // ...
};

let firstClicked = null;

document.querySelectorAll("button").forEach(button => button.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  const letter = event.target.name;

  if (firstClicked) {
    console.log(`...then ${letter}`)
    const toSay = combinations[firstClicked + letter] || "Nothing to say!";
    console.log(toSay);
    firstClicked = null;
  } else {
    console.log(`You clicked ${letter}...`)
    firstClicked = letter;
  }
}))
```

```html
<button name="a">A</button>
<button name="b">B</button>
<button name="c">C</button>
<button name="d">D</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can treat each button as a bit in a 4-bit number giving 16 combinations. When a button is clicked, set or clear the correct bit and show the word:

```js
// The 16 words
let strings = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et".split(' ');

// The index of the current word (binary)
let bin = 0;

// Add event listeners to each check box
let checks = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (let item of checks) {
  item.addEventListener('click', event => {
    // Get or set the correct bit
    const val = parseInt(event.srcElement.value);
    if (event.srcElement.checked) {
      bin |= val;
    } else {
      bin &= ~val;
    }
    // Update the output
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = strings[bin];
  });
};
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="A" value="1">
  <label for="A">A</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="B" value="2">
  <label for="B">B</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="C" value="4">
  <label for="C">C</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="D" value="8">
  <label for="D">D</label>
</div>
<div>
  <span id="output"></span>
</div>
```